# Language for starting and ending with same symbol

Tags: formal-languages

Alphabet = {a,b}
should null string be the part of this language?
L ={^,a,b,aa,bb,abba ......}
I have seen on different sources not including null string.
Is null string a part of this language or not?

Comment: some sources are saying null string should be a part of this language

Comment: https://scanftree.com/automata/dfa-string-example-17

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-to-build-a-dfa-to-accept-strings-that-start-and-end-with-same-character/

Answer (score 2):

When confronted to an ambiguous english definition of a language, you can do one of the following:

- ask for precision to the person giving the exercise/statement;
- chose arbitrarily one of the suitable formal definition;
- study all the suitable formal definitions.

If it is an exercise, it is more likely that either of the definitions (with or without the empty word) are good enough to reach the objective of the question.